# KnockoutJs How can I get the `if` binding to work inside of a template block?

Tags: templates, if-statement, knockout.js

So the [`if`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) binding of KnockoutJs is powerful, but I need to use it in a template block because I have to bind nested content E.G. `<UL>`'s.

```
<script id="my-template3" type="text/html">
    <span data-bind="if:IsInherited">foobar</span><br />
</script>
```

This doesn't seem to render no matter what `$data.IsInherited` is set to. How can one perform an if databind in a tempate block using KnockoutJs?

Comment: Can you reproduce it off of this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/PN7U9/

Comment: Are you using jquery.tmpl because if that is included I believe the control flow bindings will not work in script blocks. Using native only will solve that.

Comment: @mad after looking over things more carefully there was a script ref to jquery.tmpl post that as answer and i'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in the comments.

Are you using jquery.tmpl because if that is included I believe the control flow bindings will not work in script blocks.

Using native only will solve that

Cheers